# How to use -thread compiler flag with ocamlbuild?

Tags: ocaml, ocamlbuild

I am using `Jane Street`'s `async_core` by adding `package(async_core)` in `_tags`.

When I use `ocamlbuild -use-ocamlfind -I src test/test_airport.native`, it gives me the following error:

> camlfind ocamlopt -linkpkg -package async_core -package unix -package
>   netclient -package mongo -package xml-light src/airport.cmx
>   test/test_airport.cmx -o test/test_airport.native ocamlfind: Error
>   from package `threads': Missing -thread or -vmthread switch

---

I googled it and here is what I got http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml-4.00/manual039.html

It says:

> Programs that use system threads must be linked as follows:
>
> ```
>     ocamlc -thread other options unix.cma threads.cma other files
> ```

So I changed my ocamlbuild command like this:

`ocamlbuild -use-ocamlfind -cflag -thread -I src test/test_airport.native`

But the error remains the same. also the actual command that ocamlbuild generated remains the same without `-thread`.

---

How can I deal with this?

Comment: Who hates me so much that downvote every my question?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

What you want to know is whether there is an ocamlbuild tag (~ feature) to add the `-thread` argument to the relevant command-lines, instead of hacking it with `-cflag` in unsatisfying ways. As explained [in this blog post](http://gallium.inria.fr/blog/quick-tip-the-ocamlbuild-documentation-option/), you should use the `-documentation` option of ocamlbuild:

```
% ocamlbuild -documentation | grep thread
flag {. byte, link, ocaml, program, thread .} "threads.cma -thread"
flag {. link, native, ocaml, program, thread .} "threads.cmxa -thread"
flag {. doc, ocaml, thread .} "-I +threads"
flag {. compile, ocaml, thread .} "-thread"
```

So the answer is: add `-tag thread` to your ocamlbuild invocation
line, or just `thread` in the relevant place in `_tags`.

Comment: In the very unlikely case that gasche's answer was not clear enough here is a _tags file janestreet used in one of their talks: https://bitbucket.org/yminsky/core-hello-world/src/85769e337d3e70a4b9e3246503f59991c109afe8/_tags?at=default

Comment: thanks. I think I haven't understood the tag things in ocamlbuild

Comment: @JacksonTale, in another words, you have to create a `_tags` file in the directory where you are compiling your project. `ocamlbuild` will search for flags in the `_tags` file and invoke the necessary command with the corresponding flags for the files that you've specified in the `_tags` file.